# Coset Enumeration

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have read some material on Coset Enumeration. Unfortunately I could not follow the steps in Todd-Coexeter Algorithm, and also in Handbook of Computational Group Theory by Derek Holt. The problem is how we scan an element of subgroup and deduce the results by coset tables. How we make cost tables.

Comment: I know this method rather good, but cannot get what is your problem? Or where are you got stuck. :)

Comment: At least, give us a sample of your work.

Comment: I want to know how we construct coset enumeration table? For example G=<x,y| x^2,y^3,(xy)^2> H=<x> so Y={x} How can we construct coset table for this group. I could'nt follow it properly.

Comment: How is it useful and how do we construct for defining and scanning elements in it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I can do it for you but without a blackboard, it is really hard for me to explain what exactly is happening in this method. Sorry.

Comment: Could you please define anything about coset enumeration that what it does, how is it helpful. anyexample to define whatever you like, please. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11752/discussion-between-siddiqua-and-b-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The last table tells us that if we set $H=\langle x\rangle$ of order $2$, then $[G:H]=3$. So $|G|=6$. But $$1(xy)=(1x)y=1y=2\neq3=2x=(1y)x=1(yx)$$ so the group is not abelian an therefore $G$ could be $S_3$.

Comment: How do we know 1^y=2 and 2^y=3 in second table. similarly others.

Comment: 1^y = 2 is the definition of 2. So it's true by definition. Similarly for 2^y=3. In terms of cosets, 1 is the coset $H$ and 2 is the coset $Hy$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Thank you Sami, Thank you Amy for your supportive actions. :-)